# Error "Provisional headers are shown" on chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, google-chrome

I created an api, when I call it have to remove an image from database. As database I used mongodb, and to manage images I use gridfs.

This is the code that calls api that remove an image from database.

```
vm.delete = function(img){        
    $http.delete(baseImage + img)
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

And this is the code of API

```
gfs.exist({_id: req.params._idImg}, function (err, found) {
    if(found){
        gfs.remove({ _id: req.params._idImg }, function (err) {
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            repliesManager(res, 200, {"message":"OK"}, "OK");
        });
    }
});
```

But when I call this API, the image is cleared, but the server stops, and the result is an error. It gives me this error only if you use Chrome, and the error is "Provisional headers are shown".

This is the code of repliesManager

```
module.exports = function(res, status, data, message, err) {
    var respObj = {
        error: err,
        data: data,
        message: message
    };

    res.status(status);
    return res.json(respObj);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The response isn't being processed by the browser, most likely because it hasn't been received, most likely because it hasn't been sent. Since the remove operation apparently succeeds, the problem may be in your repliesManager component or in the way you're calling it. Posting that code here would allow further analysis, as would the error output of your server.

Comment: I have just modified the question. I posted the code of repliesManager @user2839251

Comment: That all looks reasonable. However, you say your server "stops" but you don't mention any error message or output on the server side. Is there really nothing in the console? Perhaps instead of `throw err` try `repliesManager(res, 500, {"message":err.message}, err.message, err)`.

Comment: I had put this code in the try/catch block and for this I omitted the repliesManager. I call repliesManager in the catch. The error print in the console is `MongoError: file with id 56e7b8fd321d5bec1f233d91 not opened for writing`. But the document with id **56e7b8fd321d5bec1f233d91** it will be eliminated